# add parentheses around output variables

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Given the following code:

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dR

i have not managed to get as output the parentheses i need around each variable.
Iitry with:
({sbf[@cd = 'a']})

The above will output () whenever {sbf[@cd = 'a']} does not exist.
Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<O-PM>
   <ListRcs>
      <rc>
         <mdtd>
            <rc>
               <title xml:lang="el">(Christoph Kolumbus) (Julie Nat) / (Darius Milhaud) (Erich kleiber) ; (Franz Ludwig Horth)</title>
            </rc>
         </mdtd>
    
      </rc>
      <rc>
         <mdtd>
            <rc>
               <title xml:lang="el">(Chris Prante) : ("Chris Dietz")  </title>
            </rc>
         </mdtd>
      </rc>
   </ListRcs>
</O-PM>
```

How the above could be achieved?
if i surround the variables with parentheses,ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer already showed you to output some characters only when your data exists by using it at the right side of the map operator `!`: `{sbf[@cd = 'a']!('(',.,')')}`. That might introduce spaces so perhaps you rather want `{sbf[@cd = 'a']!('(' || . || ')')}`.